# Chrome DevTools: files lose link with workspace

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Javascript files loaded into Google Chrome DevTools often lose their link with the workspace (the green dot disappears) when I'm revising code. The effect is that simple saves no longer work (I have to use 'save as' from the right-click menu) and debugging often stops. Using the 'Add folder to workspace' button has no effect.

I have to close DevTools down and reopen it, a considerable nuisance. I've looked around online but can't see any reports of this happening to others.

Is this a known problem with DevTools or might there be something I'm not setting up correctly?