# Chrome/Add Folder To Workspace - looses link to CSS

Tags: css, google-chrome

CSS files loaded into Chrome Dev tools often loose the link. The green dot disappears after reloading, and the changes haven't been saved.

Same question has been already asked here:
[Chrome DevTools: files lose link with workspace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57607600/chrome-devtools-files-lose-link-with-workspace).

But with focus on JS.

More details about the setup:
I work with a wordpress installation, and the problem remains, no matter which folder I add to workspace.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround for the problem is:

1. Rename the css file
2. Reload the page so that the css is missing
3. Rename the css file to the original name
4. Magically the changes you did are NOT LOST and it works again for some time, but it looses connection after some changes again